# Unable to terminate a batch file while running from powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have created a batch file which runs an exe file remotely, i'm sending that batch file to destination location and run the batch through powershell.

batchfile.bat

```
f:
cd \test\exe
testsql.exe  >> c:\temp\testsqllog.txt
```

this pull somedata to server and log will create to testsqllog.txt 
but testsql.exe is not getting ended, I want to end the batch file by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and confirming by <kbd>y</kbd>.

As i'm running this through powershell remotely <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is not working, if I'm giving like below

batchfile.bat

```
f:
cd \test\exe
start testsql.exe  >> c:\temp\testsqllog.txt
timeout /t 60
taskkill /im testsql.exe /f
```

getting error with `timeout /t` also if I'm killing the testsql.exe logfile is not updating.

I there another way to execute this process?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send to background, after start your timeout

`start "" /b testsql.exe   //to background execution...`
`timeout.exe /t 60        //your countdown`

```
@cd /d "f:\test\exe"
@start "" /b .\testsql.exe  >>"c:\temp\testsqllog.txt"
@%windir%\system32\timeout.exe /t 60

@%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /im testsql.exe /f
```

- Or...

```
@start "" /b /d "f:\test\exe" testsql.exe >>"c:\temp\testsqllog.txt"

@%windir%\system32\timeout.exe /t 60
@%windir%\system32\tasklist.exe |find /i "testsql.exe" && (
@%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /f /im testsql.exe /t )
```

Comment: maybe `%__APPDIR__%` instead of `%windir%\system32`?

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 Well both work perfectly...